# Merge multiple GPX to one

Tags: qgis, gpx

I have several gpx files of different routes that I want to join and then import to an route planner programm.

So far I have importet the gpx files to QGIS. After that I have converted them into shapefiles and then merged these shapefiles into one singel shapefile. Then I saved it as a gpx file.

The problem now is that if I import the gpx file to the route planner programm, it only importes one of the inital routes and not the whole joined route.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Take care of the difference between GPX routes and tracks: http://www.gdal.org/drv_gpx.html . By default, QGIS exports as a route, which can only be a single line.

Answer (score 2):

I have found working with .gpx files in both ArcMap and QGIS, there are a lot of unexpected results. [GPS Babel](http://www.gpsbabel.org/) is a free download that I use to join multiple GPS files and create either a shapefile or kml from that (you can also create a single .gpx from multiple files).

Answer (score 1):

I've more or less this problem. I couldn't merge a several kml or gpx in QGIS. But Google has solved my problem, in myMaps you can load this files and export into a one single .kml.